# Would've --- And Question

Tags: subjunctives

I have a question about these sentences. I would like to know which one is correct.

A)

1. I would have stayed at home and do nothing.
2. I would have stayed at home and did nothing.
3. I would have stayed at home and done nothing.

---

B)

1. I would have gone to Europe and go shopping.
2. I would have gone to Europe and went shopping.
3. I would have gone to Europe and gone shopping.

For me, A1 implies a hypothetical instance in the sense of 'if it were me, I would've...', and A2 implies that I regretted something in the past and I would've done something differently. A3 feels wrong to me.

Same applies to B1 and B2. But I'm on the fence about B3. It feels right... but wrong at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**A3 and B3 are correct. The others are wrong**

Auxiliary verbs, such as "have" and "would", apply to subsequent verbs when joined by "and" or other conjunctions.

I **would** **have** stayed at home and done nothing ---> I **would have** stayed at home and **would have** done nothing.

I would **have** gone to Europe and gone shopping ---> I **would** **have** gone to Europe and **would have** gone shopping.

The same is true for longer lists.

**Examples**

I **will read** and **answer** your question, then **check** my answer and **type** it.

I **am reading** and **answering** your question, then **checking** my answer and **typing** it.

I **have** **read** and **answered** your question, then **checked** my answer and **typed** it.

---

**Note**

Auxiliary verbs distribute over a list.

It works like the distributive property in maths https://www.mathwarehouse.com/dictionary/D-words/distributive-property-definition-and-examples.php